# Maven build Could not resolve dependencies - Failed to collect dependencies at

Tags: maven

I am trying to maven build an pom.xml file that I will attached the code below, it takes roughly 6 minutes every build and towards the end it always fails giving the error I will put after the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>HTTP Plugins</name>
  <groupId>io.cdap</groupId>
  <artifactId>http-plugins</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
      <comments>A business-friendly OSS license</comments>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <developers>
    <developer>
      <name>CDAP</name>
      <email>cdap-dev@googlegroups.com</email>
      <organization>CDAP</organization>
      <organizationUrl>http://www.cdap.io</organizationUrl>
    </developer>
  </developers>

  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/data-integrations/http.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:data-integrations/http.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/data-integrations/http.git</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
  </scm>

  <issueManagement>
    <url>https://issues.cask.co/browse/CDAP</url>
  </issueManagement>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype.release</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <site>
      <id>cdap</id>
      <url>http://cdap.io</url>
    </site>
  </distributionManagement>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <properties>
    <awaitility.version>3.1.6</awaitility.version>
    <cdap.version>6.1.1</cdap.version>
    <commons.version>3.9</commons.version>
    <common.codec.version>1.12</common.codec.version>
    <gson.version>2.8.5</gson.version>
    <hadoop.version>2.3.0</hadoop.version>
    <httpcomponents.version>4.5.9</httpcomponents.version>
    <hydrator.version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</hydrator.version>
    <jackson.version>2.9.9</jackson.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <jython.version>2.7.1</jython.version>
    <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
    <spark2.version>2.1.3</spark2.version>
    <unxml.version>0.9</unxml.version>
    <wiremock.version>1.49</wiremock.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cdap.cdap</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdap-api</artifactId>
      <version>${cdap.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cdap.cdap</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdap-etl-api</artifactId>
      <version>${cdap.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cdap.cdap</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdap-formats</artifactId>
      <version>${cdap.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
          <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.thekraken</groupId>
          <artifactId>grok</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cdap.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>hydrator-common</artifactId>
      <version>${hydrator.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
      <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
          <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
          <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
          <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
          <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
          <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-guice</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cdap.cdap</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdap-etl-api-spark</artifactId>
      <version>${cdap.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>${spark2.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>${spark2.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm</groupId>
          <artifactId>reflectasm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
          <artifactId>curator-recipes</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <!-- excludes scala-compiler and scala-reflect to avoid conflicting with the one from spark-repl -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <!--
          Need to exclude this since Spark brings in an older version that makes
          S3 not work in local sandbox. This doesn't affect distributed mode.
        -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>net.java.dev.jets3t</groupId>
          <artifactId>jets3t</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>asm</groupId>
          <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>${commons.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>${common.codec.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
      <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
      <version>${awaitility.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>${httpcomponents.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>${gson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.nerdforge</groupId>
      <artifactId>unxml</artifactId>
      <version>${unxml.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.python</groupId>
      <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
      <version>${jython.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- tests -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cdap.cdap</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdap-etl-proto</artifactId>
      <version>${cdap.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cdap.cdap</groupId>
      <artifactId>hydrator-test</artifactId>
      <version>${cdap.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.cdap.cdap</groupId>
          <artifactId>cdap-api-spark</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.cdap.cdap</groupId>
          <artifactId>cdap-spark-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
          <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- necessary for integration tests -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.16.Final</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cdap.cdap</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdap-data-streams2_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>${cdap.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cdap.cdap</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdap-data-pipeline2_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>${cdap.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cdap.cdap</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdap-spark-core2_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>${cdap.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>${mockito.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
      <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
      <version>${wiremock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>-Xmx3g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
            -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
          </argLine>
          <redirectTestOutputToFile>${surefire.redirectTestOutputToFile}</redirectTestOutputToFile>
          <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
          <reportFormat>plain</reportFormat>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.io.tmpdir>${project.build.directory}</java.io.tmpdir>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*TestsSuite.java</include>
            <include>**/*TestSuite.java</include>
            <include>**/Test*.java</include>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
            <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
          </includes>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*TestRun.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>2.14</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.rat</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-rat-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.10</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
            <artifactId>doxia-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>rat-check</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>LICENSE*.txt</exclude>
                <!-- This file should be not be there, but I am excluding it for now -->
                <exclude>*.rst</exclude>
                <exclude>*.md</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.cdap</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.yaml</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.md</exclude>
                <exclude>logs/**</exclude>
                <exclude>.git/**</exclude>
                <exclude>.idea/**</exclude>
                <exclude>**/grok/patterns/**</exclude>
                <exclude>conf/**</exclude>
                <exclude>data/**</exclude>
                <exclude>plugins/**</exclude>
                <exlcude>**/*.patch</exlcude>
                <exclude>**/logrotate.d/**</exclude>
                <exclude>**/limits.d/**</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.json</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.json.template</exclude>
                <exclude>**/MANIFEST.MF</exclude>
                <!-- exclude any hack classes -->
                <exclude>**/org/apache/hadoop/**</exclude>
                <!-- exclude resource files-->
                <exclude>**/resources/**</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>validate</id>
            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
            <configuration>
              <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
              <suppressionsLocation>suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
              <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
              <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
              <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
              <excludes>**/org/apache/cassandra/**,**/org/apache/hadoop/**</excludes>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>6.19</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.cdap</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdap-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <cdapArtifacts>
            <parent>system:cdap-data-pipeline[6.1.0-SNAPSHOT,7.0.0-SNAPSHOT)</parent>
            <parent>system:cdap-data-streams[6.1-SNAPSHOT.0,7.0.0-SNAPSHOT)</parent>
          </cdapArtifacts>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>create-artifact-config</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>create-plugin-json</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <_exportcontents>io.cdap.plugin.http.*</_exportcontents>
            <Embed-Dependency>*;inline=false;scope=compile</Embed-Dependency>
            <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
            <Embed-Directory>lib</Embed-Directory>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>bundle</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

After trying to build it a few times, i get the following error:

```
 BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  06:09 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-06T00:32:28+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project http-plugins: Could not resolve dependencies for project io.cdap:http-plugins:jar:1.4.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at io.cdap.cdap:hydrator-test:jar:6.1.1 -> io.cdap.cdap:cdap-unit-test:jar:6.1.1 -> io.cdap.cdap:cdap-explore:jar:6.1.1 -> org.apache.hive:hive-exec:jar:1.2.1 -> org.apache.calcite:calcite-core:jar:1.2.0-incubating -> org.pentaho:pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm:jar:5.1.5-jhyde: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.pentaho:pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm:jar:5.1.5-jhyde: Could not transfer artifact org.pentaho:pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm:pom:5.1.5-jhyde from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [datanucleus (http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2, default, releases), glassfish-repository (http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish, default, disabled), glassfish-repo-archive (http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish, default, disabled), apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots, default, snapshots), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases), conjars (http://conjars.org/repo, default, releases+snapshots)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I have downloaded the newest version of maven but I really struggle to understand the issue as I am a novice, so any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The problem is simply because you are using http instead of https ..`from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories:`...

Comment: See for more details the release notes: https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html

Comment: @khmarbaise you are a life-saver! so, just so I get it straight, I need to go through the pom.xml and change every "http" to "https" ? or did i misunderstand what needs to be changed?

Comment: @khmarbaise please do advise on how to change from http to https! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Go to maven's configuration file **conf/settings.xml** and comment out the following.

```
   <mirror>
      <id>maven-default-http-blocker</id>
      <mirrorOf>external:http:*</mirrorOf>
      <name>Pseudo repository to mirror external repositories initially using HTTP.</name>
      <url>http://0.0.0.0/</url>
      <blocked>true</blocked>
   </mirror>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check with settings.xml configuration since there might be some updates and its better to take working repository(in.m2) from team .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).